# prevent image url from malicious code and sql injection

Tags: regex, sql-injection

I'm using regex `(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif))` to validate image url and it's working, but still some unwanted user could put a code like this in the image url:
`http://avatar/image'OR''='/someimage.jpg` and I wonder if there is another regex can detect special character like `'` and `;`

Comment: Give up the idea of guarding against SQLi by using blacklists. Make your DB access secure instead, by parameterizing your queries and doing whatever you platform allows you to do in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever rely on regex for protecting your database against sql-injection. Use `parameterized queries` instead for user input inside sql-statements.